# onClick not work on LinearLayout with child Switch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-switch

I've got a custom LinearLayout with a widget `Switch` and `TextView` child. I'd like to be able to click the area covered by the `LinearLayout`, so I set `clickable=true` to the `LinearLayout`, but `Switch` is not triggered.

I wanted to trigger on `Switch` when I click on the `LinearLayout`.
I also tried with `android:duplicateParentState="true"` in `Switch` but did't worked. 

Can I achieve this from `XML`?

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Switch
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Visibility"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="@string/visibility_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have to implement `OnClickListener` and change state there

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman No, I want to achieve this from xml because `Switch` toggle without any listener

Comment: when you click linear layout that you have change Switch  status

aSwitch.setChecked(true);//

Comment: @ThavaSelvan your answer is applicable.

Comment: @ThavaSelvan I want to achieve from `XML`

Comment: @VijayKumar Have you tried my below answer?

Comment: @DipankarBaghel Not working

Comment: @VijayKumar I have tried when I click the layout it changes the switch state.

Answer (score 1):

Set **Id** of your **linearlayout** and **Switch** and when your perform click of Linearlayout you must want to perform checked of Switch.

```
linearLayout.setOnClickListener
{
   onClick()
   {
      Switch.setChecked(true);}
   }
}
```

Comment: @VijayKumar You can't achieve it from XML because you should perform click of switch or linearlayout as per your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to obtain required output

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Visibility"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="@string/visibility_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then set setOnClickListener of linearlayout:

```
 lnrLayout.setOnClickListener{
            switch.performClick()
        }
```

Or you can use switch with text.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                style="@style/tvStyle_poppinsMedium_Small_Black"
                android:text="@string/push_notifications"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I want to achieve from `XML`

Comment: I don't think it is possible to connect click event of two view from XML.
You can also achieve required result by using switch with text and required style.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to achieve via xml -

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/ripple"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Switch
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Visibility"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:text="@string/visibility_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="58dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```